# How to convert word's formula to string for save database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, latex, mammoth

I have project in NodeJs+React where Word files are imported through mammoth npm, I am faced with a problem with processing formulas in this Word file. After import, mammoth cannot process formulas and leaves them empty. How to convert these formulas into Latex format so that they can be edited in the front-end part in the future with React.

Should I somehow convert the Word files before importing, or can I make that after importing into the Postgres database? Because that data from Word file should be saved in Postgres db.

The formulas in a Word file look something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SznAP.jpg)

They say on the Internet that you can write a VBA module that converts formulas into text format so that you can then import them through mammoth npm. But I didn’t understand what exactly to write in these scripts so that they would convert all the formulas in the Word file.

Comment: Word files are essentially a zip archive with directories and XML files. If you don't care about the formatting, and you only want to get the text (and formulae), you could unzip the file, and then collect the contents of `word/document.xml`. The formulae are within the `<m:oMath>...</m:oMath>` keys. Then again, there's [this](https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js/issues/83) (though, [this](https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js/issues/83#issuecomment-617036986) in the same discussion seems to address your needs).